# How is the "I" current calculated in this circuit?

Tags: current, diodes

[image]

I found Vo with these processes

[10 - (- 2)] / (1200   4700) = 2.033mA
1200 * 0.002033 = 2,43V
Vo = 10 to 2.43 = 7,57V

but I can't find the "I" current. Can you help me?

Comment: your Vout might be wrong, you haven't taken into consideration the diode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find I it is a similar process and you can take credit for the fact that there is no load at Vo

1. Determine the voltage difference: 10V ->  -2V  = 12V
2. remove additional voltage drop: assume diode is 0.6V: 12 - 0.6V = 11.4V
3. calculate current through the resistive chain:  11.4/(1200+4700) = 1.932mA